# How to draw without lines in between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

[[image: .]]

Hi I'm trying to draw the image below without the line going through the nodes but I can't seem to figure it out. Below is the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.5in,right=1.5in,margin=1.5in]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{tikzpicture} [scale = 0.4]
\tikzstyle{vertex} = [circle, fill = black!10]
\tikzstyle{edge} = [thick]

\node[vertex](v1) at (0,0){1};
\node[vertex](v2) at (3,0){2};
\node[vertex] (v3) at (6,0) {3};
\node[vertex](v4) at (9,0){4};
\node[vertex](v5) at (12,0){5};
\node[vertex](v6) at (15,0){6};
\node[vertex](v7) at (18,0){7};
\node[vertex](v8) at (21,0){8};
\node[vertex](v9) at (24,0){9};
\node[vertex](v10) at (27,0){10};
\node[vertex](v11) at (30,0){11};
\node[vertex](v11) at (33,0){12};
\node[vertex](v13) at (36,0){13};


\draw [edge](v1) --(v13);

\path 
(v1) edge [bend left] node {} (v13)
(v3) edge [bend left] node {} (v11)
(v5) edge [bend left] node {} (v8)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are sophisticated ways of doing this, but the simplest (conceptually) is to use `\draw (v1)--(v2)--(v3)--(v4)--(v5)--(v6)--(v7)--(v8)--(v9)--(v10)--(v11)--(v12)--(v13);`. Note also that your MWE is missing `\begin{document}` and has two nodes named `(v11)`. I'm assuming the second should be `(v12)`.

Answer (score 2):

See if the following solution works for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning
                }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm,
  start chain = A going right,   % <---
vertex/.style = {circle, fill=gray!30, 
                 minimum size=1.3em, inner sep=0pt,
                 font=\small\bfseries,
                 on chain=A, join = by arr,
                 },
   arr/.style = {-, semithick},
                       ]
    \foreach \i in {1,...,13}
\node[vertex]   {\i};
%
\path[arr, bend left=45]
    (A-1) edge  (A-13)
    (A-3) edge  (A-11)
    (A-5) edge  (A-8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**

- for positioning of nodes are used `chains` and `positioning` packages
- nodes names is defined by `start chain = A going right`; so the first node name is `A-1` and the last in your case is `A-13`
- distances between nodes are determined by `node distance`; it define distance between nodes' borders
- lines between nodes are draw by the `chains` package macro `join`.
- in your document class options you have a mess, for page layout is added the `geometry˙ package

Comment: Thank you so much.